# MariaDB 10.5.16 Server Grinding to a Halt with "Opening tables"

Tags: mariadb

We have a MariaDB server (10.5.16) that has recently become pretty unreliable. A simple query like `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LIMIT 1` hangs with "Opening tables" as the state (and is still at "Opening tables" 30 minutes later). On another server that query returns in 200ms.

A simple insert in a small table takes 15 seconds. The server has 32 GB of RAM, a 500 GB SSD, plenty of available disk space, and runs CentOS 7.9.2009.

Here is the output of `SHOW VARIABLES \G`:
https://pastebin.com/yZZ1HNEm

I updated innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5GB (the previous value * 40) using SET GLOBAL, and will switch innodb_flush_method to O_DIRECT on the next restart.

Any ideas on why everything has ground to a halt? I'm seeing quite a few in a state of "Opening tables".

Any settings you'd change? As the innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128MB implies this server hasn't been optimized and I'm still the new guy so change is incremental.

Thanks!

Comment: `show global status` and `show global variables` would be ideal. Any query optimizations on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*` are adhoc (hence only somtimes simple), so your "simple query" is really opening every table. and the `LIMIT 1` isn't being applied to the end. As such you've probably ran out of [`table_open_cache`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#table_open_cache). Once that's resolved your `insert` will hopefully have resolved itself.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of available RAM.  The `VARIABLES` you provided still says 128M, which is much too small.  How many tables do you have?  If you re=fetch the VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS, please do the 1-value-per line, not the `\G` format.